# How to talk down a suicidal person when time is of the essence

Tags: criminology

From what I gather, the standard tactic for talking down someone who wants to kill themselves is to play for time (until help arrives, until the person changes their mind, etc.).

But what about scenarios in which every second counts? The reason I'm asking is because I read that the pilot of Germanwings Flight 9595, who was locked out of the cockpit by his suicidal first officer, spent the last few minutes before the crash banging on the door, yelling and swearing at the first officer as the plane steadily descended towards the Alps. I can imagine that yelling and swearing isn't a particularly effective way of talking down a suicidal person, but what approach could have worked in this situation with better odds of success?